# Data type error for tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices... Cannot convert a TensorShape to dtype: <dtype: 'float32'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to take data from a csv with a list of files and a list of labels, and convert it to being one-hot labeled for a categorical classification using tf.keras. I am using eager mode for the code.

I'm trying to follow the tf.data example from CS230 building a data pipeline.

https://cs230-stanford.github.io/tensorflow-input-data.html

my code is below under the code section.

the csv file that lists the location of all the pictures is located on dropbox here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5uo8o1p30g2aeta/Clock.csv?dl=0

When I run the code as shown below I get a

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a TensorShape to dtype: <dtype: 'float32'>
error.
```

When I add to line 55 and make line 56 :

```
one_hot_Hr = tf.one_hot(file.Hr,classes)
one_hot_Hr = tf.to_int32(one_hot_Hr)
```

I get this  error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Mul as input #0 was expected to be 
a float tensor but is a int32 tensor [Op:Mul] 
name: loss/activation_2_loss/mul/
```

when I run

```
iterator.get_next()
```

the pictures are formated as

```
<tf.Tensor: id=12462, shape=(32, 300, 300, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
```

the labels are formated as:

```
 <tf.Tensor: id=12463, shape=(32, 13), dtype=float32, numpy=
```

based on the errors, it seems like it should be a simple formatting issue with the labels, but I'm stumped and neither error brings up much useful information on stack overflow.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as k
#import cv2
#tf.enable_eager_execution()
#import argparse
#from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense



def parse_function(filename, label):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)

    # Don't use tf.image.decode_image, or the output shape will be undefined
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)

    # This will convert to float values in [0, 1]
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)


    image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [300, 300])
    return image, label



def train_preprocess(image, label):
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)

    image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=32.0 / 255.0)
    image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, lower=0.5, upper=1.5)

    # Make sure the image is still in [0, 1]
    image = tf.clip_by_value(image, 0.0, 1.0)

    return image, label

batch_size = 32
classes = 13

fileLoc = "C:/Users/USAgData/TF/Clock.csv"
file = pd.read_csv(fileLoc)
file['Loc']=''
file.Loc = str(str(file.Location)[9:23] + str(file.Location)[28:46])


one_hot_Hr = tf.one_hot(file.Hr,classes)
#one_hot_Hr = tf.to_int32(one_hot_Hr)



dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file.Loc, one_hot_Hr))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(len(file.Location))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls=4)
dataset = dataset.map(train_preprocess, num_parallel_calls=4)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

#print(dataset.shape) # ==> "(tf.float32, tf.float32)"

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

#print(next_element)

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

model_name="Documentation"
model = k.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(300,300,3))) #Changed shape to include batch
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

#model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
#model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

#model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
#model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax')) #Changed from sigmoid




#changed from categorical cross entropy
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(.0001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()



fitting = model.fit_generator(iterator,epochs =1 ,shuffle=False, steps_per_epoch=14400//batch_size)


#model.evaluate(dataset,steps=30)


import sys
print(sys.version)
tf.__version__
```

I'm running:
tf: 1.10.0
Python: 3.6.7 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 10 2018, 20:35:02) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]

I don't know if this should truly be the solution, but when I switch:

```
fitting = model.fit_generator(iterator,epochs =1 ,shuffle=False, steps_per_epoch=14400//batch_size)
```

to

```
fitting = model.fit(iterator,epochs = 1 , shuffle = False, steps_per_epoch = 14400//batch_size)
```

The model does start to train. But, then them model runs out of data points because the iterator will not start over again.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Error disappears if you upgrade the Tensorflow to 1.14.